# How to access Administrative console in Keycloak docker

Tags: keycloak

I am running Keycloak 16.1.1.  in docker container. I can access  admin console  as

x.x.x.x.:9443/auth/admin/master/console/#/realms/myrealm/clients

However if I set in   docker_compose file

KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=htttps://www.mydomain.com/auth

I can no longer access admin console at port 9443

Doc at ([www.keycloak.org/server/hostname](http://www.keycloak.org/server/hostname))  has an option  --hostname-admin-url

I have tried to guess and set KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_URL in docker compose but it did not work.  How can access admin console at a different URL ?